# Display a random css Sprite with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a current script that displays a random icon from an array of 200-300 file names. This works.

I have a new found interest in self contained files/apps.

Can I choose a random sprite from a css sprite sheet and display it at the press of a button using js or jQuery?

I'm not looking for complete code here...just a general idea of what that would entail.

Comment: Ye​s, y​o​u c​a​n.​​​​

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would approach it .if you have a sprite sheet with different sprites on it . You use JS to append a different classes to it all representing different position in the sprite sheet

```
 <style>
   img_1{
    width:120px;
    height:123px;
    background-image:url('Images/newcampaign_sprite2.png');
    background-position:0px 0px;
   }
   img_2{
    width:120px;
    height:123px;
    background-image:url('Images/newcampaign_sprite2.png');
    background-position:10px 10px;
    }
   </style>


<body>
    <img id='foo1'>


    <script>
   //Initiate the variables 
   let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1  ;
   let classwithSpritePos ='';

   //check what random is between 1-3 and apply the sprite position class
   if(random == 1){classwithSpritePos = 'img_1'; }
   if(random == 2){classwithSpritePos = 'img_2'; }

       let img = document.getElementById('foo1');
       img.classList.add(classwithSpritePos);

</script>
```